# Could not find tools.jar. Please check that /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home contains a valid JDK installation Asked

Tags: java, build

I follow the method that tomfriwel provided(Could not find tools.jar. Please check that /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home contains a valid JDK installation), but I got a message from terminal like this

> cp: /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar: Permission denied

Before this, I did like that

> cp '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_271.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar' /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/

How can I solve this? Please help me to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

To install the JavaAppletPlugin you have to install the Oracle JDK version 8 or an old Apple Java version 1.6.

Apple Java 1.6 can be downloaded from https://support.apple.com/kb/dl1572?locale=en_US.

Oracle JDK 8 can be downloaded from https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase-jdk8-downloads.html

Answer (score 0):

> export the following into ~/.zshrc

#Java SDK
export JAVA_HOME=/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

steps to do that:

- open terminal
- vim ~/.zshrc
- Press I
- paste the above code
- enter :wq

now it will work